# Locking down a folder in apache to not allow php or any other server side code (html ONLY)

Tags: php, security, apache

I've got a side project where users will be uploading zip files containing html code. This is mostly sanitized (only customers can do this) but it still places me in "high alert mode". The only thing customers can upload are html/binary/javascript files (so html, htm, js, gif, png, jpeg, swf). I would prefer that these get uploaded to a webserver that only supports html code.

Here's my thought process

Step 1: User uploads zip through php

Step 2: PHP extracts zip file to "HTML only land" in webserver

Step 3: Folder is then reviewed/approved

Step 4: Client receives url from upload

How can I best do step 2? If I'm running apache could I say that "folder x cannot run any php code or executables"? Say I create a folder called /var/www/dangerdanger what sort of restrictions should I apply to "dangerdanger" so that it doesn't allow the execution of any code?

To reiterate I'm not looking for protection from the "dirty unwashed masses" these would be clients. Sure, someone else could steal a client login or an angry employee might try to do something unhelpful. That's why I need some level of server-side-security.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: AFAIK, there is little you can do to prevent them from including malicious code even with HTML only. Think of the HTML page on your site as a loader program for off-site data.

Comment: Hey Horatio, I understand the dangers of XSS and redirects. That's expected. I do not want them to be able to run code THAT COULD DAMAGE THE SERVER. If they redirect/xss/create a dummy page that can be dealt with. But if they build a PHP script that deletes folders or injects data into OTHER folders then we have a problem.

Comment: ensure that your server configuration and scripts dissallow upload of dot files as well. Also ensure that defaulthandler is set so they can't manipulate a file name to get a script running.

Answer (score 1):

Just use .htaccess to remove processing of code files in that folder. This can be done using:

```
RemoveHandler .php
```

You might want to review what you server can run and duplicate this line for each possible webserver language. Obviously there might other things, but HTACCESS will be the way to go to disable the features you don't want in a specific folder.

Note: You might have to get a decidated server to do this. I don't think AddHandler and RemoveHandler will be normally allowed on shared/reseller hostings